# Find index of last occurrence for each value

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have a vector like this :

```
>> v = [1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5]'

v =

     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     3
     4
     4
     4
     4
     4
     5
     5
```

The vector is sorted. There can be any number of each values. I need to find the index of the last occurence of each value. In this case, it would return this :

```
answer =

     3    % index of the last occurence of "1"
     5    % index of the last occurence of "2"
     6    % index of the last occurence of "3"
    11    % index of the last occurence of "4"
    13    % index of the last occurence of "5"
```

Comment: The accepted answer works for an unsorted group as well. So the same would be true for `v=[1 2 1 2 2 3 4 5 4 4 4 5 5 6]'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @trumpetlicks, the answer is `unique`.

```
>> v = [1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 6]'

v =

     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     3
     4
     4
     4
     4
     4
     5
     5
     6

>> [~, answer] = unique(v)

answer =

     3
     5
     6
    11
    13
    14
```

[EDIT]
In more recente version of the MCR (R2013 ?), the behavior of `unique` has changed. To get the same result, you must use `unique(v, 'legacy');`

Comment: I am on R2014a and this does not work. In fact it returns `answer =

     1
     4
     6
     7
    12
    14`

Comment: I _think_ you can pass a second parameter to unique since R2013 that says that it should the former behavior. Try `unique(v, 'Legacy')` or something like that.

Comment: Yup this works `[~, answer] = unique(v, 'legacy')` yields `answer =

     3
     5
     6
    11
    13
    14`
I should have checked the function help... Please do add this to your answer. ;)

Comment: This works for an unsorted array too. Thanks! 
Combined with `find` you can retrieve data for that row.

Answer (score 5):

```
v = [1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5];
find(v==1,1,'last')
 % returns ans = 3
find(v==2,1,'last')
 % returns ans = 5
```

the 1 gives the number of occurrences you want to return, and `'first'` or `'last'` may be specified

Comment: while true, the OP likely wants an automated way to get the index of the index of the last occurrence of every value in a big vector. If there are 20 million values, this solution is going to be a bit rough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[find(diff(v')) length(v)]
```

You should be able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: The line itself does not works : Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent. `find(diff(v))` gives the result I want, but does not works if there's only one occurence of the last value. For exemple if adding a sigle `6` at the end of the vector.